# Hide page title if the image field has a value

Tags: 8, theming

I have a image field (field_image) on my content type. I want to show the image below the header with the node title inside. I am successfully doing that in page.html.twig.

```
{% if node.field_image %}
  <div id="feature-image">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="feature-image">{{ node.label }}</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

However, the page title is also showing up in the page title block inside of the Header region. I'm trying to find a way to hide the second page title, on the full node view, if the field_image field has a value.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: node.label has the title of that node!! What value you want to print there instead??

Comment: Yes, I am using {{ node.label }} to print in the #feature-image div. However, it's also showing up in the Page title block. I'd like to hide the block altogether if `field_image` has a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method works for me. (Thanks to kim.kennof on Slack for the assistance.)

In my **THEME.theme** file:

```
function THEME_preprocess_page_title(&$variables) {
  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\Entity\Node) {
      $variables['node'] = $node;
    }
  }
}
```

Then in **page-title.html.twig**:

```
{% if node.field_image is empty %}
  {% if title %}
    <h1{{ title_attributes.addClass('page-header') }}>{{ title }}</h1>
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: `if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\Entity\Node)` would be a lot more robust for the condition

Comment: @Clive Do you mean instead of `if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node'))`?

Comment: No the inner condition. Better to check that something _is_ the single thing that it should be, rather than _isn't_ all the things it shouldn’t be

Comment: Ahh, of course, makes sense. Code updated and works great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You an add a [hook_block_access](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_access/8.5.x) to a .module file in a custom module.

Include these use statements at the top of the file

```
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
```

Then implement your hook like so.

```
/**
 * Hide page title block when the node being viewed has a hero image.
 *
 * Implements hook_block_access()
 */
function ifde_blog_block_access($block, $op, $account) {
  if ($block->id() == 'REPLACE_WITH_PAGE_TITLE_BLOCK_ID' && $op == 'view') {
    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    if ($node instanceof NodeInterface && $node->hasField('field_image') && !empty($node->field_image->getValue())) {
      return AccessResult::isForbidden();
    }
  }
  return AccessResult::neutral();
}
```